# Need image above the products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

i need image in this url above the products
https://vitalticks.com/new-offer-zone.html
For reference please find the below link
https://pinkblue.in/special-offers/weekly-premium-deals.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to add a banner above the products?

- If so, navigate to **Admin -> Catalog -> Categories**
- On category section (right hand side), select category you wish to add the banner to.
- In the "Content" tab, click on "upload" next to "category Image"
- Upload your image and save the category.

Answer (score 2):

After reading your question, I think that you are asking about the image which is displayed on the top off all products. Actually that image is the category image which you can add from the backend as follows.

- Catalog->Categories->Edit New Offer Zone Category->Content->Add the
  category Image->Save Your Category